# Read replicated messages from ibm-mq

Tags: java, db2, replication, ibm-mq

I have a replication for DB2 via ibm-mq. I have to read this messages and and based on this messages change system. I need a library for transform messages that described in this topic 
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSTRGZ_11.4.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.ep.xmlpubsguide.doc/topics/iiyexpmgrtransac.html
to java objects. If somebody know the library it will safe my time.

Event example from link

```
    <trans isLast="is_last_indicator" segmentNum="segment_number"
  cmitLSN="commit_logical_sequence_number" cmitTime="commit_time"
  authID="authorization_ID" correlationID="correlation_ID"
  planName="plan_name">

  elements

</trans>


  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<msg xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="mqcap.xsd"
version="1.0.0" dbName="DB1">
<trans isLast="1" segmentNum="1" cmitLSN="0000:0000:0000:06d6:87ab:0000:0000"
  cmitTime="2015-10-31T12:12:12.000122">

  insertRow, updateRow, or deleteRow

</trans>
</msg>


  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<msg xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="mqcap.xsd" version="1.0.0"
dbName="DB1">
<trans isLast="1" segmentNum="1" cmitLSN="0000:0000:0000:06d6:87ab:0000:0000"
  cmitTime="2003-10-31T12:12:12.000122">
  <insertRow subName="S1" srcOwner="USER1" srcName="T1">

    column_element

  </insertRow>

  <deleteRow subName="S1" srcOwner="USER1" srcName="T1">

    column_element

  </deleteRow>

  <updateRow subName="S1" srcOwner="USER1" srcName="T1">

    column_element

  </updateRow>
</trans>
</msg>
```

Comment: I have a replication for DB2 via ibm-mq

Comment: that link is dead ("The request cannot be fulfilled by the server")

Comment: strange - it works for me

Comment: You can edit the question by clicking "edit" and change it to state 'ibm-mq' instead of 'abc-mq'.

Comment: I am also unable to get to that link in either Chrom or IE "The request cannot be fulfilled by the server".  Can you explain what the topic describes?  Normally for QREP you have it on both ends, not sure what related to QREP you need to transfrm to java objects?

Comment: I don't know much about Java or XML, but I have always assumed that if you have the schema for the XML messages, you can manipulate them. Are you essentially asking for the schema for these XML messages?

Comment: I am not asking about schema - my question is to find the library to work with this schemas

Comment: This really isn't an MQ question but rather a DB2 question.  You are using InfoSphere Data Replication's component to insert (replicate) MQ messages to a table in DB2.  Now you want to read that DB2 table.  Simply open the DB2 table with a standard database tool, export the table layout then build your JDBC calls based on the table layout to extract whatever row/columns you want.